# git log --since doesn't include expected commits

Tags: git

`git log` by itself correctly shows all commits dated back to year 2017.

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h - %ad: %s" --date=iso  --follow  Website/Consumer/Integration/Symitar/SymitarManager.ascx.vb
1a3c6a12f94 - 2018-09-04 22:23:43 +0000: Aloha Pacific / Kekaha, OTS - setup new sublender files BugzID: 290945
bb1d88516af - 2018-09-02 17:28:39 +0000: Symitar/AlabamaTeachers: Use correct entity IDs BugzID: 280366
980b3b27dd0 - 2018-09-02 17:22:43 +0000: Symitar/AlabamaTeachers: Hardcode entity IDs for hotfixing BugzID: 280366
d89b81c17f5 - 2018-08-21 22:14:51 +0000: Symitar / North Carolina Community FCU - new client files BugzID: 289842
78f2cd94c88 - 2018-07-23 23:57:25 +0000: Symitar / Our CU - Updated to use correct Lender ID BugzID: 284792
0ddd6f1c553 - 2018-07-23 23:28:23 +0000: Symitar / Our CU - New Client Set Up BugzID: 284792
7762c503a65 - 2018-07-11 17:58:57 +0000: Symitar / Family First of NY FCU - New client setup for Loans; Fixed typo for XA. BugzID: 284785
d451f1da03e - 2018-07-11 00:27:54 +0000: Symitar / Family First of NY FCU - New client setup for XA. BugzID: 284785
aa67549bcc8 - 2018-06-16 00:21:59 +0000: when booking to to core, stop updating member number to consumer user profile if originator is from Guest User
9dff3157603 - 2018-06-14 23:24:50 +0000: Symitar / Belco Community CU - New client setup. BugzID: 278625
23b95301600 - 2018-06-06 17:57:45 +0000: Symitar / Oswego County - fixed missed psLenderID parameter BugzID: 279373
0abeecd1bfe - 2018-06-05 21:26:28 +0000: Symitar / Oswego County FCU - New Client Set Up BugzID: 279373
fd19b93a965 - 2018-06-01 18:28:24 +0000: Symitar / Alabama Teachers FCU - New Client Set Up BugzID: 280366
512ac6c1aea - 2018-04-30 23:21:14 +0000: Symitar - Altana: add core integration files BugzID: 262811
bcb6d02f3f4 - 2018-04-23 21:09:41 +0000: Symitar/BlackHills: Use Symitar entityID BugzID: 269914
83e801987b8 - 2018-04-23 14:04:05 +0000: Symitar / Black Hills FCU - added new client files. BugzID: 269914
f9bc3ead00b - 2018-03-29 01:40:51 +0000: Symitar - Avadian: site build BugzID: 272555
1a1b607aa83 - 2018-02-05 23:37:36 +0000: Symitar - Cardinal community: site build BugzID: 265958
fa865ba1e03 - 2018-02-05 21:52:08 +0000: Symitar - One Nevada: site build BugzID: 258594
18bac793b23 - 2018-01-26 01:34:33 +0000: Symitar/West Virginia Central: site build BugzID: 257648
3b00b5396a3 - 2018-01-12 00:51:40 +0000: Symitar/Langley: Symitar site build for Langley BugzID: 257399
ac202d0bbe0 - 2017-12-30 00:35:08 +0000: symitar/kern schools - KERN_SCHOOLS_SYMITAR_LENDER_ID BugzID: 258454
32b76717919 - 2017-12-20 20:45:22 +0000: symitar/kern schoools - create loans/XA files BugzID: 258454
b28ad3311dc - 2017-10-12 23:32:03 +0000: Symitar / McGraw Hill FCU - New client file setup. BugzID: 253107
20c4cdd9a13 - 2017-08-28 16:54:28 +0000: Remove debug code. BugzID: 247618
......

$
```

However, if I use `git log --after='2018-01-01'`, the output doesn't have commits between 2018-02-05 and 2018-01-12 .

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h - %ad: %s" --after='2018-01-01' --date=iso  --follow  Website/Consumer/Integration/Symitar/SymitarManager.ascx.vb
1a3c6a12f94 - 2018-09-04 22:23:43 +0000: Aloha Pacific / Kekaha, OTS - setup new sublender files BugzID: 290945
bb1d88516af - 2018-09-02 17:28:39 +0000: Symitar/AlabamaTeachers: Use correct entity IDs BugzID: 280366
980b3b27dd0 - 2018-09-02 17:22:43 +0000: Symitar/AlabamaTeachers: Hardcode entity IDs for hotfixing BugzID: 280366
d89b81c17f5 - 2018-08-21 22:14:51 +0000: Symitar / North Carolina Community FCU - new client files BugzID: 289842
78f2cd94c88 - 2018-07-23 23:57:25 +0000: Symitar / Our CU - Updated to use correct Lender ID BugzID: 284792
0ddd6f1c553 - 2018-07-23 23:28:23 +0000: Symitar / Our CU - New Client Set Up BugzID: 284792
7762c503a65 - 2018-07-11 17:58:57 +0000: Symitar / Family First of NY FCU - New client setup for Loans; Fixed typo for XA. BugzID: 284785
d451f1da03e - 2018-07-11 00:27:54 +0000: Symitar / Family First of NY FCU - New client setup for XA. BugzID: 284785
aa67549bcc8 - 2018-06-16 00:21:59 +0000: when booking to to core, stop updating member number to consumer user profile if originator is from Guest User
9dff3157603 - 2018-06-14 23:24:50 +0000: Symitar / Belco Community CU - New client setup. BugzID: 278625
23b95301600 - 2018-06-06 17:57:45 +0000: Symitar / Oswego County - fixed missed psLenderID parameter BugzID: 279373
0abeecd1bfe - 2018-06-05 21:26:28 +0000: Symitar / Oswego County FCU - New Client Set Up BugzID: 279373
fd19b93a965 - 2018-06-01 18:28:24 +0000: Symitar / Alabama Teachers FCU - New Client Set Up BugzID: 280366
512ac6c1aea - 2018-04-30 23:21:14 +0000: Symitar - Altana: add core integration files BugzID: 262811
bcb6d02f3f4 - 2018-04-23 21:09:41 +0000: Symitar/BlackHills: Use Symitar entityID BugzID: 269914
83e801987b8 - 2018-04-23 14:04:05 +0000: Symitar / Black Hills FCU - added new client files. BugzID: 269914
f9bc3ead00b - 2018-03-29 01:40:51 +0000: Symitar - Avadian: site build BugzID: 272555

$
```

Why doesn't `git log --since` work? How do I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I tried format %cd, which shows commit date. The results are the same .

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h - %cd: %s" --date=iso  --follow  Website/Consumer/Integration/Symitar/SymitarManager.ascx.vb
1a3c6a12f94 - 2018-09-04 22:23:43 +0000: Aloha Pacific / Kekaha, OTS - setup new sublender files BugzID: 290945
bb1d88516af - 2018-09-02 17:28:39 +0000: Symitar/AlabamaTeachers: Use correct entity IDs BugzID: 280366
980b3b27dd0 - 2018-09-02 17:22:43 +0000: Symitar/AlabamaTeachers: Hardcode entity IDs for hotfixing BugzID: 280366
d89b81c17f5 - 2018-08-21 22:14:51 +0000: Symitar / North Carolina Community FCU - new client files BugzID: 289842
78f2cd94c88 - 2018-07-23 23:57:25 +0000: Symitar / Our CU - Updated to use correct Lender ID BugzID: 284792
0ddd6f1c553 - 2018-07-23 23:28:23 +0000: Symitar / Our CU - New Client Set Up BugzID: 284792
7762c503a65 - 2018-07-11 17:58:57 +0000: Symitar / Family First of NY FCU - New client setup for Loans; Fixed typo for XA. BugzID: 284785
d451f1da03e - 2018-07-11 00:27:54 +0000: Symitar / Family First of NY FCU - New client setup for XA. BugzID: 284785
aa67549bcc8 - 2018-06-16 00:21:59 +0000: when booking to to core, stop updating member number to consumer user profile if originator is from Guest User
9dff3157603 - 2018-06-14 23:24:50 +0000: Symitar / Belco Community CU - New client setup. BugzID: 278625
23b95301600 - 2018-06-06 17:57:45 +0000: Symitar / Oswego County - fixed missed psLenderID parameter BugzID: 279373
0abeecd1bfe - 2018-06-05 21:26:28 +0000: Symitar / Oswego County FCU - New Client Set Up BugzID: 279373
fd19b93a965 - 2018-06-01 18:28:24 +0000: Symitar / Alabama Teachers FCU - New Client Set Up BugzID: 280366
512ac6c1aea - 2018-04-30 23:21:14 +0000: Symitar - Altana: add core integration files BugzID: 262811
bcb6d02f3f4 - 2018-04-23 21:09:41 +0000: Symitar/BlackHills: Use Symitar entityID BugzID: 269914
83e801987b8 - 2018-04-23 14:04:05 +0000: Symitar / Black Hills FCU - added new client files. BugzID: 269914
f9bc3ead00b - 2018-03-29 01:40:51 +0000: Symitar - Avadian: site build BugzID: 272555
1a1b607aa83 - 2018-02-05 23:37:36 +0000: Symitar - Cardinal community: site build BugzID: 265958
fa865ba1e03 - 2018-02-05 21:52:08 +0000: Symitar - One Nevada: site build BugzID: 258594
18bac793b23 - 2018-01-26 01:34:33 +0000: Symitar/West Virginia Central: site build BugzID: 257648
3b00b5396a3 - 2018-01-12 00:51:40 +0000: Symitar/Langley: Symitar site build for Langley BugzID: 257399
ac202d0bbe0 - 2017-12-30 00:35:08 +0000: symitar/kern schools - KERN_SCHOOLS_SYMITAR_LENDER_ID BugzID: 258454
32b76717919 - 2017-12-20 20:45:22 +0000: symitar/kern schoools - create loans/XA files BugzID: 258454
b28ad3311dc - 2017-10-12 23:32:03 +0000: Symitar / McGraw Hill FCU - New client file setup. BugzID: 253107
20c4cdd9a13 - 2017-08-28 16:54:28 +0000: Remove debug code. BugzID: 247618
4a1cab2e647 - 2017-08-23 23:45:07 +0000: Add debug code BugzID: 247618
...
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely problem here is that `--since` or `--after` tests the *committer* date, while `%ad` shows you the *author* date.

Normally, the committer date would be *later* than the author date, if the two differ, as the author date would be copied from an earlier commit that was cherry-picked or otherwise reworked in some fashion.  Here the author date would be the time the original commit was created, while the committer date would be the time the commit you have now was made.  So `%ad` might show a date in early January, even though the commit was finalized in late Jan or Feb.

Still, the fact that the two dates can be different is the most likely source of the issue.  To see whether that's the case, look at any of the "missing" commits using `--pretty=fuller` or similar.  You can do this with `git show` or `git log`, e.g.:

```
$ git log --no-walk --pretty=fuller  | sed 's/@/ /'
commit c05048d43925ab8edcb36663752c2b4541911231
Author:     Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
AuthorDate: Tue Sep 4 14:33:27 2018 -0700
Commit:     Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
CommitDate: Tue Sep 4 14:33:27 2018 -0700

    Git 2.19-rc2

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

In this case the two dates are the same, but consider this commit:

```
commit 6c6ce21baa9b50d394bb8ed9878944504ffd57d8
Author:     Eric Sunshine <sunshine sunshineco.com>
AuthorDate: Fri Aug 31 04:33:42 2018 -0400
Commit:     Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
CommitDate: Fri Aug 31 12:05:24 2018 -0700
```

which shows how the author and committer are different people with different time-stamps.

(There is no `--since` equivalent that examines author date instead of committer date.)

Comment: Hi, I tried format %cd, the results are the same.. There are still commits missing.

Comment: OK. In this case you're probably being bitten by Git's attempt to not search down branch paths that seem uninteresting, which can happen if merge commits have incorrect date stamps (e.g., are performed on computers whose clock is set wrong). I'm not sure off-hand how to check for this, nor what if anything can be done about it other than cranking your `--since` setting lower.

Comment: That may be the cause. This is git-svn repository. I saw there were SVN commits whose timestamp is 0, ie. year 1970 or so. When they were imported to Git, there might be something wrong.